# Is it possible to use the Disruptor/Ringbuffer pattern without using a fixed-length array?

Tags: disruptor-pattern

We have a Disruptor implementation that has a fixed-length array.  Is it possible to implement  a version of the pattern that does not rely on this array, but instead contains (possibly self-describing) lists of variable length objects.  For example, a Ringbuffer of Protobuf objects?

I'm aware that the fixed-length array is for the "pre-allocation" step, but I consider it possible to approximate that step with one or more object pools.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want something like a growing ringbuffer that will only grow up to a specific amount before reusing oldest memory (e.g. for event logs or similar things)?

Comment: I need a more flexible ringbuffer.  I've inherited a system that's predicated on one, but has few/no low latency requirements.  Adding new parameters or testing out new ideas is incredibly difficult to the inflexibility of the fixed-length array.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something due not having used this specific pattern, but what new parameters? How is the array "inflexible"?

Answer (score 1):

The ringbuffer in the java version of the disruptor is any array of references to objects. You can put whatever objects you want in there through the EventFactory instance you create.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible to implement a version of the disruptor that isn't backed by an Object array but it won't be high performance. A lot of thought and mechanical sympathy has gone into the design and implementation of the LMAX Exchange Disruptor.

Essentially the ring buffer is an pre-allocated object pool. From my experience, I've never had to worry about managing the ring buffer's resources directly in any real world code. The disruptor will automatically apply back pressure when necessary.

The library provides a nice DSL to construct a dependency graph for your application and basically gives you parallelism for free.